# Probability Waves vs. Amplitude Waves

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, wavefunction, probability

It is often asserted, and it is common knowledge, that the waves associated with a particle are probability waves.
This seems reasonable. But what about $E=hf$? This does not seem to be about probability.

Is it the case that sometimes we are dealing with one type of wave, and sometimes with another?

Comment: $E=hf$ refers to the energy of a photon. It bears no relation to probability waves.

Comment: why is that a problem? Imagine you have a plane electromagnetic wave in classics. There is an energy associated to the wave calculated from its pointing vector

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are two different types of waves involved here. In classical electrodynamics an [electromagnetic wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation) describes how the magnitude and direction of the electric and magnetic fields vary with time and with position in physical space. In quantum mechanics a [wave function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function) describes how the complex-valued probability amplitude of a quantum system varies with time and with position in the system's [configuration space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_space_(physics)), which is an abstract space of possible configurations of the system.

When we say that $E=hf$ for a photon, the frequency $f$ is *both* the frequency of the quantum wave function for that photon *and* the frequency of the electromagnetic wave which would classically represent a population of photons with the same energy $E$; in other words, the classical electrodynamic frequency and the quantum wave function frequency of a photon have the same value.

Answer (score 0):

[In this double slit one photon at a time](https://www.sps.ch/artikel/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/) experiment one sees the interference pattern coming from classical electromagnetic waves in the last frame on the right,

[image: singlphot]

> 1. Single-photon camera recording of photons from a double slit illuminated by very weak laser light. Left to right: single frame, superposition of 200, 1’000, and 500’000 frames.

The first frame shows the distribution of single photons that make up the classical interference. At the quantum level, the last frame is the probability distribution for  the experiment "photon scattering off double slit given width and dimensions" the $Ψ^*Ψ$ of those boundary conditions .

$E=hν$ is the energy of the photons used in the experiment, where $ν$ is the frequency of the classical wave

In one experiment two types of waves give the interpretation of the data. The reason the classical wave and the quantum probability wave have the same frequency you will find in the reference [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0604169), in a nutshell, because  quantized Maxwell equations are used to get the wave function of a photon, so the quantized equation  solutions are related to the classical equations.

Comment: Anna, it is taking me a while to fully digest the article on Maxwell. It is amazing that he came before Einstein. I note that a photon can be seen as a disturbance in an electromagnetic field, also that probability features a lot.

Comment: Anna, Also I am a little surprised by the idea of relativistic quantum mechanics. One reads a lot about the incompatibility of QM and Relativity........As to your images of interference,[ the first picture shows as just black. Should there be one dot there?......PS I like your Fayum image.

Comment: Anna, Sorry, it seems that the probability has to do with Dirac and later interpretations of Maxwell.

Comment: @marek  " the first picture shows as just black." in my browser (firefox) the left frame has a number of ~70 faint green dots,. The reference is for how the Maxwell equations can be quantized, analogous to the Dirac etc.  Quantum mechanics and relativity go hand in hand in Dirac and Klein Gordon equations, it is the  Schrodinger one that is incompatible to special relativity, that why the others were discovered, to make everything compatible.

Comment: My question might seem a little naive. How many photons produced the pattern in the first frame. I think you only give numbers for the last three. I thought it was a single photon and that a single photon would result in a single dot in a random position....Thanks for telling me that it is only the Schrodinger equation that is incompatible with relativity. Why is it incompatible. Is it just because of the Schrodinger equation that they keep saying that QM and SR are incompatible? One reads about the desire for a Grand Unifying Theory...PS have you read about the ideas of David Deutsch, MWI etc

Comment: @Marek each dot is a photon fooprint, I said I counted about 70

Comment: Yes, so calle first quanization equations do not follow Lorentz invariance.  Second ( dirac etc do) and so does quantum field theory built on dirac etc.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that the result in the first frame was of the firing of a single photon. In which case there would have been one randomly located dot. It seems that it was the result of lower intensity light. Now I can see faint dots........Single photon experiments have been done, I believe. This gives a dot in a random position. However, if you repeatedly fire single photons then you get the full interference pattern.

Comment: There are some physicists eg. Deutsch who think that single photon interference is the result of the photon interfering with another from a different world. I am sure you think that is nonsense. It seems to me that a single photon as a wave can show interference.I would like to hear your ideas, even though it might seem a little off topic.

Comment: @m sorry, in the standard model a single photon is an elementary **point** particle with a specific (x,y,z,t)

Comment: And the single photon never exhibits wave behaviour?

Comment: @Marek the wave part of particles is a **probability wave**, it needs an accumulation of same boundary and conditions events to be seen.

Comment: Yes I understand that it is a probability wave. But nevertheless such waves cause interference. And a single wave passing through two slits would cause interference. Just as a single wave in a river passing two openings into a pond would cause interference. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The equation $E=h f$ is rather an experimental fact (from the blackbody radiation or the photoelectric effect). It says that the particles with energy $E$ have an associated wave with frequency $f$ and vice versa. But it is not really clear at this point that this wave is a probability wave. This probabilistic behaviour of particle can be well shown in the double slit experiment with electrons. Other experiments showed that this probabilistic wave should also obey the relation $p = \frac{h}{\lambda}$. From these two experimental fact we can say that a wave function with energy $E$ and momentum $p$ can be written as:

### $\begin{align}\psi(x,t) = A \cdot e^{-i \cdot 2 \pi f t} \cdot e^{\frac{i \cdot 2 \pi}{\lambda}x}= A \cdot e^{-i \frac{ E }{\hbar}t} \cdot e^{i \frac{ p}{\hbar}x} \end{align}$

From this you can "derive" the Schrödinger equation etc. Scientists then realised that we could think of the square of this wave function as the probability for a particle to be measured at $x$ to the time $t$.

So this long story was to show you that $E = hf$ is an experimental fact that tells you how the probabilistic wave function evolves over time. It is not a consequence of the probabilistic behaviour.